# How do I activate a javascript button as if a user clicked it?

Tags: javascript, html, button

How do I activate a javascript button as if a user clicked it? Could I run javascript code
to activate the button? (supposing I did not already know the code in the button, and I am on a random website where I can not change existing code)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="aaa.php">
      <input type="text" />
      <input id="button" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      var btn = document.getElementById("button");
      //is there anything like: btn.click?
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax of the inline handler is invalid. If that's really the HTML markup you have, you can't run it as-is - it needs to be fixed first. But even still, [don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have a demented scope chain, require global pollution, and have quote escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: `document.getElelementById("button").click();`

Comment: A `;` is missing after your alert.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni While I agree that one should not rely on automatic semicolon insertion, the fact that it's not added here is not an error, nor related to the question or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <button id="button"onclick="myFunction()">b</button>
  <!--creates the button-->
  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("button");
    btn.click();
    
    function myFunction(){
       alert('working');
       }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way you can handle it, call a specific function from your `onClick`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <button id="button" onclick="clickButton()">b</button>
  <!--creates the button-->
  <script>
    function clickButton() {
       alert("hello!");
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

To answer your question more directly, this is one way you can do it

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick=function(){/* some code */}
```

Comment: I don't think you read/understood the question. You didn't actually answer what was being asked.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, You can separate out HTML and javascript.

**Sample.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <button id="button">Click Here</button>
    <button onclick="onClickBtn(this)">Click Here 2</button>
    <!--creates the button-->
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementById("button");
        btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            alert("Hi")
        })
        function onClickBtn(event) {
            alert("Btn 2")
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've re-written the OPs code nicely, but you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: What is the answer than ?

Comment: Is there any code language other than English ? @ScottMarcus

Comment: The question wasn't asking about how to set up event listeners. It was asking how to automate the `click` event. I've posted the one line answer in the comment below the question.

Comment: I think u only understand, rest of the others are equally didn't get the CODE WORD. The word activates me to enable, He didn't ask how to trigger.

Comment: I think it's very clear. He said "as if a user clicked it", which is about as clear as can be. Also, @DCR understood and posted a correct answer.

Comment: yes after reading our count and 30 min later after the post. :D

Comment: He actually posted his answer 1 minute before you did.